# Fluent / Nhibernate: could not retrieve snapshot

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, automapper

I am trying to map a many to many relation with Fluent NHibernate but it is not working for me. I am mapping the entities with AutoMapper. I get this error when I try to map;

> {"could not retrieve snapshot:
>   [Models.AccountsGroup_Accounts#Models.AccountsGroup_Accounts][SQL:
>   SELECT chartofacc_.fkGroupID, chartofacc_.fkAccountID FROM
>   AccountsGroup_Accounts chartofacc_ WHERE
>   chartofacc_.fkGroupID=? and chartofacc_.fkAccountID=?]"}

Tables are;

```
1. Accounts (table name)
   AccountID,
   AccountName

2. AccountsGroup (table name)
   AccountGroup_ID,
   GroupName

3. AccountsGroup_Accounts (table name)
   fkAccountsID,
   fkAccountsGroup_ID
```

Table AccountsGroup_Accounts only holds primary keys of Accounts and AccountsGroup table as forigen keys but also make a composite key out of them for itself.

**Model Classes are;**

```
 public class Account
        {
            public virtual int Id { get; set; }
            public virtual string AccountName { get; set; }
            public virtual IList<AccountGroup> AccountGroups { get; set; }
        }
public class AccountGroup 
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string GroupName { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
    }

public class AccountsGroup_Accounts 
    {
        public virtual Account Accounts { get; set; }
        public virtual AccountGroup AccountGroups { get; set; }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            var compare = obj as AccountsGroup_Accounts;
            if (compare == null)
                return false;

            return (Accounts.Id == compare.Accounts.Id && AccountGroups.Id == compare.AccountGroups.Id);
        }
        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return (Accounts.Id + "|" + AccountGroups.Id).GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

**Mappings are;**

```
public AccountGroupMapping()
        {
            SetEntityProperties("AccountGroups", "Group_ID");
            Map(x => x.GroupName);
            HasManyToMany<Account>(x => x.Accounts)
             .Table("AccountsGroup_Accounts")
             .ParentKeyColumn("fkGroupID")
             .ChildKeyColumn("fkAccountID")
             .LazyLoad(); 
        }
public AccountMapping()
        {
            SetEntityProperties("Accounts", "AccountID");
            Map(x => x.AccountName);
            HasManyToMany<AccountGroup>(x => x.AccountGroup)
             .Table("AccountsGroup_Accounts")
             .ParentKeyColumn("fkAccountID")
             .ChildKeyColumn("fkGroupID")
             .LazyLoad(); 
        }
public AccountsGroup_Accounts()
        {
            Table("AccountsGroup_Accounts");
            CompositeId().KeyReference(x => x.AccountGroup, "fkGroupID")
                .KeyReference(x => x.Account, "fkAccountID");
        }
```

Non model classes (these are generated from xsd2code);

```
public partial class Accounts
    {
        public int AccountIdField {get; set;}
        public string accountNameField {get; set;}
  }
public partial class AccountGroup
    {
        public int accountGroupIdField {get; set;}
        public string groupNameField {get; set;}
    }
public partial class AccountsGroup_Accounts
    {
        public int AccountGroupsRefId  {get; set;}
        public int AccountsRefId { get;set;}
    }
```

**And this is how I map them:**

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Account, Models.Account>()
                .ForMember(x => x.Vat, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(new VatRefIdResolver(loadRepository)).FromMember(x => x.VatRefId));
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<AccountGroup, Models.AccountGroup>();

AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<AccountsGroup_Accounts, Models.AccountsGroup_Accounts>()
                .ForMember(x => x.Account, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(new AccountResolver(loadRepository)).FromMember(x => x.AccountRefId))
                .ForMember(x => x.AccountGroup, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(new AccountGroupIdResolver(loadRepository)).FromMember(x => x.AccountGroupRefId));
```

So this is what I have done so far. Now I don't know what and where I am missing something and what else needs to be done so solve that problem or many-to-many mapping.

I will be very grateful if someone could help me to identify the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out the problem myself. I was getting the error because the name of the junction table was not correct. It suppose to be **AccountsGroupRelation** instead of **AccountsGroup_Accounts**.

As soon as I fixed it everything started working.